# How to declare an int type that will be calculated with map.size()

Tags: c++, stl

I have a member variable called `mySize`, and I want to calculate the difference from the size of a map, say `myMap`. Which type should I use when declare `mySize`? I'm using uint32_t now.
E.g.,
In `myClass.h`:

```
  static uint32_t getDifference(std::map<string, int> myMap);
  static uint32_t mySize_;
```

In `myClass.cpp`:

```
uint32_t getDifference(std::map<string, int> myMap){
  return std::abs(mySize_ - myMap.size());
}
```

UPDATE: Critical bug in the above code. `std::abs` can't be used for `uint32_t`. But this is not too much related to the question. I should use `std::size_t` instead of `uint32_t`.

Comment: The type for this is `size_t`.

Comment: you copy whole map just to ask it's size? that's pretty original

Comment: Why don't you check the reference: [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), [`std::map::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/size). Alternatively, you may look up the source code

Comment: As a side note, you must prefer using `std::map<string, int>& myMap` instead of `std::map<string, int> myMap` (ideally though, as per @Slava's comment, you should not be doing this just for *size*).

Comment: @abhishek_naik: a non-`const` reference prevents you calling it with a `const` map, it should instead be `getDifference(const std::map<string, int>& myMap)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[community wiki as much of this information's already posted as comments]

It should be:

```
std::map<string, int>::size_type getDifference(const std::map<string, int>& myMap)
{
    return mySize_ >= myMap.size() ? mySize_ - myMap.size()
                                   : myMap.size() - mySize_;
}
```

The code above checks which is larger to avoid a subtraction like `2 - 3`, which for unsigned types creates a very large number because `-1` can't be represented: `abs()` happens too late to prevent that, and does nothing to the very large number it sees.

In practice, using `size_t` is often done as it's easier to type and read, is almost always what the implementation uses for `size_type`, and regardless - it's sure to be large enough.